# Confusion about currying and point free style in Haskell

Tags: haskell, currying, pointfree

I was trying to implement the function

```
every :: (a -> IO Bool) -> [a] -> IO Bool
```

which was the topic for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160170/language-showdown-lazy-aka-short-circuit-evaluation-for-and-and-or-applied-to). I tried to do this **without explicit recursion**. I came up with the following code

```
every f xs = liftM (all id) $ sequence $ map f xs
```

My function didn't work since it wasn't lazy (which was required in the question), so no upvotes there :-).

However, I did not stop there. I tried to make the function **point-free** so that it would be shorter (and perhaps even cooler). Since the arguments `f` and `xs` are the last ones in the expression I just dropped them:

```
every = liftM (all id) $ sequence $ map
```

But this did not work as expected, in fact it didn't work at all:

```
    [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( stk.hs, interpreted )

    stk.hs:53:42:
        Couldn't match expected type `[m a]'
               against inferred type `(a1 -> b) -> [a1] -> [b]'
        In the second argument of `($)', namely `map'
        In the second argument of `($)', namely `sequence $ map'
        In the expression: liftM (all id) $ sequence $ map
    Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Why is that? I was under the impression that it was possible to simply drop trailing function arguments, which basically is what currying is about.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The definition of $ is

```
f $ x = f x
```

Let's fully parenthesize your function:

```
every f xs = (liftM (all id)) (sequence ((map f) xs))
```

and your curried version:

```
every = (liftM (all id)) (sequence map)
```

As you noticed, these are not identical. You can only drop trailing function arguments when they are the last thing applied. For example,

```
f x = g c x
```

is actually

```
f x = (g c) x
```

and the application of (g c) to x comes last, so you can write

```
f = g c
```

One pattern with the application operator $ is that it often becomes the composition operator . in points-free versions. This is because

```
f $ g $ x
```

is equivalent to

```
(f . g) $ x
```

For example,

```
every f xs = liftM (all id) $ sequence $ map f xs
```

can become

```
every f xs = (liftM (all id) . sequence . map f) xs
```

at which point you can drop xs:

```
every f = liftM (all id) . sequence . map f
```

Eliminating the argument f is more difficult, because it is applied before the composition operator. Let's use the definition of dot from http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree:

```
dot = ((.) . (.))
```

With points, this is

```
(f `dot` g) x = f . g x
```

and is exactly what we need to make every fully points-free:

```
every = (liftM (all id) . sequence) `dot` map
```

Sadly, due to restrictions in the Haskell type system, this one needs an explicit type signature:

```
every :: (Monad m) => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m Bool
```

Comment: Or you can use -XNoMonomorphismRestriction and drop the explicit type sig.

Comment: Argh... the `dot` definition looks like someone staring at me.