# What's the best way to mask a credit card in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, credit-card

In Node, I need to turn a credit card into something like this before rendering the view layer: `************1234`.

Without loops and ugliness is there a utility or one liner for this? The credit card can potentially look one of these ways:

```
1234567898765432
1234-5678-9876-5432
1234 5678 9876 5432
```

Answer (score 10):

No need for a regex:

```
var cc='1234-5678-9012-3456';
var masked = '************'+cc.substr(-4); // ************3456
```

Will work for any format provided the last four digits are contiguous.

Comment: I almost went this route. Amex is 15 digits with 2 spaces, and it bothered me there would be one too many asterisks lol.

Comment: card number can be from 13 up to 19 digits long, the algorithm should take into consideration at least that

Answer (score 8):

Here's one way with [Ramda](http://www.ramdajs.com) and some RegEx:

```
var ensureOnlyNumbers  = R.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
var maskAllButLastFour = R.replace(/[0-9](?=([0-9]{4}))/g, '*');
var hashedCardNumber   = R.compose(maskAllButLastFour, ensureOnlyNumbers);

hashedCardNumber('1234567898765432'); // ************5432
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/7odv6kfk/

Answer (score 4):

This is for everyone who said they didn't need another way to mask a credit card. This solution will append the last 4 chars of the card number with asterisk.

```
var cardNumber       = '4761640026883566';
console.log(maskCard(cardNumber));

function maskCard(num) {
  return `${'*'.repeat(num.length - 4)}${cardNumber.substr(num.length - 4)}`;
}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bvdhu9cg/2/)

Answer (score 4):

I use this function that is useful for me, because mask the credit card number and format it in blocks of four characters like this `**** **** **** 1234`, here the solution:

```
const maskCreditCard = (card) => {
  return card
    .replace(/.(?=.{5})/g, "*")
    .match(/.{1,4}/g)
    .join(" ");
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function hashCreditCard(number){
  const str = String(number).replace(" ","").replace("-","")
  const last = str.slice(-4)
  return last.padStart(str.length,"*")
}

console.log(hashCreditCard(5859831060602434))
console.log(hashCreditCard("5859-8310-6060-2434"))
console.log(hashCreditCard("5859 8310 6060 2434"))
```

Comment: adding an explanation would improve this answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's plain JavaScript using Regex with lookahead

```js
var cardNumbers = [
  "1234567898765432",
  "1234-5678-9876-5432",
  "1234 5678 9876 5432"
];

console.log(cardNumbers.map(maskCardNumber));
//> ["************5432", "************5432", "************5432"]

function maskCardNumber(cardNumber) {
  return cardNumber.replace(/^[\d-\s]+(?=\d{4})/, "************");
};
```

Unlike AllienWebguy's implementation:

- doesn't require an external library
- does everything in one `replace()` call
- replaces whatever number of digits with the constant number of asterisks (it should be a bit faster, but it may not be what you want)
- supports only described formats (will not work, for example, with `"1B2C3D4E5F6G7H89876-5432"` or `"1234+5678+9876=54-32"`)

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944446/what-is-point-free-style-in-functional-programming

Comment: I guess so, but what's the point? I agree, using combinators can make things simpler, but I think adding whole library or implementing your own `replace()`  just for this one function will have much higher cost than gain it provides.

Comment: That's a pretty common first reaction to FP. It's pretty short-sighted to think only this one function would be affected/improved. To each his own.

Answer (score 1):

Remove non digits, generate an asterisk string of that length - 4, append the last 4:

```
var masked = Array(cc.replace(/[^\d]/g, "").length - 3).join("*") + cc.substr(cc.length - 4);
```

Or to include space/hyphens in the mask:

```
var masked = Array(cc.length - 3).join("*") + cc.substr(cc.length - 4);
```

Comment: Nice! FYI `cc.substr(cc.length - 4)` can be simplified to `cc.substr(-4)`