# Ramda how to pass parameter into higher order function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm studying functional programming from [here](http://randycoulman.com/blog/2016/05/31/thinking-in-ramda-combining-functions/), and come across below code

```
const wasBornInCountry = person => person.birthCountry === OUR_COUNTRY
const wasNaturalized = person => Boolean(person.naturalizationDate)
const isOver18 = person => person.age >= 18

const isCitizen = person => wasBornInCountry(person) || wasNaturalized(person)

const isEligibleToVote = person => isOver18(person) && isCitizen(person)
```

Which can be shorten to below

```
const isCitizen = either(wasBornInCountry, wasNaturalized)
const isEligibleToVote = both(isOver18, isCitizen)
```

I can't seems to understand how

```
const isCitizen = person => wasBornInCountry(person) || wasNaturalized(person)
```

can be translated to below:

```
const isCitizen = either(wasBornInCountry, wasNaturalized)
```

How do we pass the parameter `person` into `wasBornInCountry` and `wasNaturalized`? What if I wish to call `isCitizen` with two parameters? How we know which parameter gonna be passed to `wasBornInCountry` and which parameter to `wasNaturalized`?

Comment: @NicholasTower: Thank you very much for the pseudocode. It gives me a clearer picture!

Comment: The point is that `either` and `both` are functions that each accepts two predicate functions are create a new predicate function out of them.  You could write them as `both = (f1, f2) => arg => f1(arg) && f2(arg)` or `either = (f1, f2) => (...args) => f1(...args) || f2(...args)` depending up whether you need to supply multiple arguments or not.  If you need more complicated scenarios where different arguments are passed to different functions, then `either` and `both` would not be enough.

Comment: You might also [read about](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) [point-free style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944446/what-is-point-free-style-in-functional-programming).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do we pass the parameter person into wasBornInCountry and wasNaturalized?

You don't. The function generated by `either` does.

> What if I wish to call isCitizen with two parameters?

Then make sure that each of the two functions you pass to `either` accepts two parameters.

```
const same = (x, y) => x == y;
const ten = (x, y) => x == 10 || y == 10;
const f = R.either(same, ten);
console.log([f(1, 1), f(2, 1), f(10, 3)])
```

> How we know which parameter gonna be passed to wasBornInCountry and which parameter to wasNaturalized?

Go and look at your original code:

> ```
> const isCitizen = person => wasBornInCountry(person) || wasNaturalized(person)
> ```

- The `person` parameter is passed to `wasBornInCountry`
- The `person` parameter is passed to `wasNaturalized`

There is only one parameter. It is passed to both functions.

If there are multiple parameters, then they will all be passed to both functions.