# Removing whitespace, tabs and new lines from array

Tags: ruby

How do I go about removing the tabs, new lines, and whitespaces from this array?

```
array1 = ["E", "A", "C", "H", " ", "L", "I", "N", "E", " ", "E", "N", "D", "S", " ", "W", "I", "T", "H", " ", "A", " ", "A", "C", "C", "I", "D", "E", "N", "T", "A", "L", "L", "Y", " ", " ", "A", "D", "\"", "A", " ", "A", "C", "C", "I", "\n", "\""]
```

I have tried the following, and none of these seem to work properly.

```
array1.map!(&:strip)

array1.reject!(&:empty?)

array1.reject(&:empty?)

array1 - [""]

array1.delete_if {|x| x == " " }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array1 = ["E", " ", ":", "L", "É", "\t", "T",
          "-", "H", "\n", "\""]

array1.reject { |s| s.match? /\s/ }
  #=> ["E", ":", "L", "É", "T", "-", "H", "\""]
```

`\s` in a regular expression matches all whitespace characters, namely, spaces, tabs (`"\t"`) newlines (`"\n"`), carriage returns (`"\r"`) and formfeeds (`"\f"`).

The latter two have their origins from the days when teletype machines were used, the carriage return being the movement of the printhead from the end to the beginning of the line and the formfeeds advancing the paper being printed one line.<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sub>1 Microsoft Windows still recognizes carriage returns and formfeeds, thereby maintaining support for teletype machines. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯</sub></sup>

Comment: Perhaps you want to see his/her second question in the accepted answer's comment.

Comment: @Sebastian, the example (which I modified slightly) should address that.

Comment: `\p{Space}` would also get rid of other unicode whitespace :)

Comment: Alternatively if you like the [point-free/tacit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944446/what-is-point-free-style-in-functional-programming) approach: `array1.reject(&/\s/.method(:match?))`

Comment: @Johan, I'm not particularly fond of that construct (which seems to be increasingly popular), but maybe that just reflects my lack of familiarity.

Comment: The concept is pretty simple. You remove the variable assignment in between and instead tell `reject` to forward the block arguments to the method `match?` on `/\s/`.

Comment: @Yes, I understand, just not sure it's worth it to avoid having a block.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) to select elements matching a pattern. That pattern can be a simple [regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html) like `/\s/` which matches whitespace characters:

```
array1.grep(/\s/)
#=> [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "\n"]
```

The result is an array with all elements containing at least one whitespace character.

There's also `\S` (uppercase) which matches non-whitespace characters:

```
array1.grep(/\S/)
#=> ["E", "A", "C", "H", "L", "I", "N", "E", "E", "N", "D", "S", "W",
#    "I", "T", "H", "A", "A", "C", "C", "I", "D", "E", "N", "T", "A",
#    "L", "L", "Y", "A", "D", "\"", "A", "A", "C", "C", "I", "\""]
```

And we have [`grep_v`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep_v) which is the inverted version of `grep`. This would be useful if you wanted to specify space, tab and newline explicitly:

```
array1.grep_v(/[ \t\n]/)
#=> ["E", "A", "C", "H", "L", "I", "N", "E", "E", "N", "D", "S", "W",
#    "I", "T", "H", "A", "A", "C", "C", "I", "D", "E", "N", "T", "A",
#    "L", "L", "Y", "A", "D", "\"", "A", "A", "C", "C", "I", "\""]
```

Comment: This is the most suitable answer imo.

Comment: @Johan, I'll second that, in part because of the he reference to `grep_v`, which I've not seen used before.  Ann, please consider moving the greenie to this answer.

Comment: Readers: repeat 100 times, "To select with a regex, think grep. To reject, grep_v."

Comment: ^ The better mnemonic would be: Can I match elements using the case equality (`===`)? If the answer is *yes* use `grep`. Another example without regex could be: `[1, 'A', :b].grep(Integer) #=> [1]` or `(1..100).grep(95..150) #=> [95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]`

Answer (score 0):

In addition, just other possible variants:

```
array1 = [" ", "A", "\n", "\t", "B", "\r"]
array1.delete_if { |s| s.match? /\s/ }
#=> ["A", "B"]
```

```
array1 = [" ", "A", "\n", "\t", "B", "\r"]
array1.keep_if { |s| !s.match? /\s/ }
#=> ["A", "B"]
```

```
array1 = [" ", "A", "\n", "\t", "B", "\r"]
array1.select! { |s| !s.match? /\s/ }
#=> ["A", "B"]
```

Using `match?` rather than `match` is more preferable not only because we don’t use `MatchData`.

The point is that the benchmark shows that `match?` is almost 2 times faster.

This can be significant when working with large amounts of data.