# What does `&method(:function)` mean?

Tags: ruby

What does `&method(:function)` mean? For example, I have this line:

```
res = integrate(0, 1, a, &method(:function))
```

Comment: Two excellent answers (so far). Lucky you!

Answer (score 19):

Say we have a method

```
def add_one(num)
  num + 1
end
```

and an array of strings

```
arr = ["1", "2"]
```

We want to `map` the list of strings to their corresponding outputs from `add_one`.

To start out we can call

```
nums = arr.map(&:to_i)
```

This is the same thing as

```
nums = arr.map do |str|
  str.to_i
end
```

You can see [What does map(&:name) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby) for more info on this.

However, it won't work to call:

```
nums.map(&:add_one)
```

Why? Because numbers have no built in method `add_one`. So you'll get a `NoMethodError`.

So, rather than providing just a *method name* `:add_one` you can pass an *bound method* `method(:add_one)`:

```
nums.map(&method(:add_one))
```

Now, rather than each num being used as the *receiver* for the `add_one` method, they will be used as *arguments*. So, it's essentially the same as:

```
nums.map do |num|
  add_one(num)
end
```

To give another example, compare the following:

```
[1].map(&:puts)
# this is the same as [1].map { |num| num.puts }
# it raises NoMethodError

[1].map(&method(:puts))
# this is the same as [1].map { |num| puts num }
# it prints 1 successfully
```

Comment: Nitpick: `Object#method` returns a *bound* `Method`, not an `UnboundMethod`. The method is *bound* to a receiver because you are calling it on an instance and it thus knows what `self` is, whereas `Module#instance_method` returns an `UnboundMethod` because it can't know what instance it will be going to be used with.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Ok thanks for the correction, you are right I must have been mixing it up with `.instance_method` because I was just going by (flawed) memory

Answer (score 12):

`method(:function)` is a *message send* (sometimes called a *method call*) to the implicit receiver (i.e. `self`). It is sending the message `method` to the implicit receiver (i.e. `self`), passing `:function` as the sole argument.

`:function` is a `Symbol` literal, i.e. it is the literal notation of a `Symbol`. `Symbol` is a data type representing "the name of something".

The unary prefix ampersand `&` operator "unrolls" a `Proc` into a *block*. I.e. it allows you to pass a `Proc` where a *block* is expected. If the object is not already a `Proc`, it will be sent the `to_proc` message allowing it to convert itself into a `Proc`. (The operator is only legal in an argument list and only for the last argument. It is the dual of the `&` sigil in a parameter list, which "rolls" a block into a `Proc` object.)

`Proc` is a datatype representing executable code. It is Ruby's core library class for first-class subroutines.

So, what this does, is call the `method` method on `self` with `:function` as the argument, call `to_proc` on the return value, "unroll" the resulting `Proc` object into a *block* and pass that block to the call to `integrate` as if you had written something like

```
res = integrate(0, 1, a) do
  # something
end
```

The `method` method here is most likely, the [`Object#method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-method) method, which returns a *bound* [`Method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html) object.

So, all in all, this is somewhat equivalent to

```
res = integrate(0, 1, a) do |*args, &block|
  function(*args, &block)
end
```

But expressed in what is commonly called [*pointfree style*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/944446/2988).